# How can I get keystrokes to be displayed on-screen in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keystroke

How can I get the keystrokes I enter to be displayed on-screen in VS Code? This would be for presenting or doing screencast.

Answer (score 40):

v.1.31 has added a screencast mode, see [toggle screencast mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_screencast-mode):

> Screencast Mode
>
> There is a new Screencast Mode in VS Code, which highlights the cursor
>   position and keystrokes. Screencast Mode (Developer: Toggle Screencast
>   Mode) can be useful for demonstration purposes.

[image: demo of screencast mode]

There are a couple of accompanying settings:

> `Screencast Mode: Only Keyboard Shortcuts`
>
> Only show keyboard shortcuts in Screencast Mode.
>
> `Screencast Mode: Vertical Offset`
>
> Controls the vertical offset of the screencast mode overlay from the
>   bottom as a percentage of the workbench height.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031202/836330.

Answer (score 4):

Carnac should work as normal in VSCode - have you launched Carnac as adminitrator? It needs elevated privileges to read input without focus.

Comment: Well look at that...the one thing I had not done. Sure enough works.

Comment: Second read and this is not actually the full reason. It has nothing to do with focus because the app I'm trying to use is the "focused" app I'm using.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the full reason this was not working is because I have VS Code starting in elevated privileges. So Carnac apparently cannot work against the application when it is not running under elevated privates as well.

I started VS Code as normal user, and start Carnac then everything works as expected.

I start VS Code as elevated user (as admin) and then Carnac has to be running in the same fashion for it to pick up the keystrokes.

Comment: VSCode screencast mode show the keys being pressed (normal typing) as well, is there any way it would only show combination keys pressed and not the normal keys I press for typing?