# VSCode - Am I able to change the font/height of the screencast?

Tags: visual-studio-code, screencast

Is it possible to change the font/height/... of the screencast? I can't find it in the settings.

Comment: It isn't mentioned in the latest release notes so I doubt you can change those things.  https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_screencast-mode

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated list of the settings available - as of v1.63 - relating to the Screencast Mode:

[image: screencast settings]

The `Timeout`, `Color` and `Mouse Indicator Size` are new as of v1.49.
The `commandAndKeys` format will show command names - as of v1.63.

---

It has been added to v1.46, see [Add ability to change screencast font size](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/88308)

`screencastMode.fontSize` // new setting