# VSC: presenting displaying entered shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use shortcut I need it to be displayed in VSC (i.e. for presentation).

Similar to `Presentation Assistant` in InteliJ:
[image]
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7345-presentation-assistant

Is there any setting, extension or code snippet to modify VSC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get keystrokes to be displayed on-screen in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733089/how-can-i-get-keystrokes-to-be-displayed-on-screen-in-vs-code) (found by googling "`vscode display keyboard input`")

Comment: @user Yes it is exactly what I was looking for - additionally https://dev.to/chris_l_ayers/presenting-with-vs-code-screencast-mode-1oa3 to present only shortcuts

Comment: Unfortunately screencast mode is not ignoring some keys so there is lot of noise in its output. There is PR to resolve this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/171845