# (Possibly Copilot Related) Unexpected "<ctrl63>" Issue in Visual Studio Code Autocompletion - Need Assistance

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, github-copilot

I'm facing a perplexing issue in Visual Studio Code where the string "<ctrl63>" is unexpectedly appearing in my code when using autocompletion. I'm pretty sure it's related to Copilot.

Here's a couple of random examples of how it just throws in the <ctrl63>:

````
  ```
 app.get (""), (req, res) => {
 res.send("This is the home page.");<ctrl63> 
     }
  ```

    '''
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const port = 3000;

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });<ctrl63> This code will create a simple web server that listens on port 3000. When a                     request is made to the root URL ('/'), the server will send the response 'Hello World!'.
 '''
````

Checking Keyboard Shortcuts: I've reviewed the keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio Code to ensure that "<ctrl63>" is not inadvertently mapped to any action.

Disabling Extensions: I've disabled all extensions in Visual Studio Code, including Copilot, to rule out any extension-related conflicts. No auto complete, no issues when Copilot is disabled.

Reviewing Code Editor Settings: I've reviewed my Visual Studio Code settings and configurations to see if there's anything that might be causing this issue, but haven't found any relevant settings.

Comment: if you can, please enter [screencast mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563456/11107541) in VS Code and then record a video of your screen that demonstrates this happening.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Please also include the version of your GitHub Copilot extension. Try also reproducing with a [new temporary profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_what-is-a-temporary-profile) (with only the GitHub Copilot extension enabled).

Comment: Also try [rolling back the GitHub Copilot extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42626065/11107541) to see if the problem reproduces in older versions. Let us know which versions you rolled back to and whether the same problem happened in each one.

Comment: Interesting - this is happening to me too, but I'm using Duet AI

Comment: what was the issue? https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: I found the issue. I started to notice a common theme that they were appearing where comments likely belong. I removed the extension 'Better Comments', and sure enough, problem solved. Must have been a conflict between it and Copilot autocomplete. Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this happens when you combine the [`aaron-bond.better-comments`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments) extension with an extension that provides inline completions such as the GitHub Copilot extension. I don't know why this happens. As a workaround, you could consider disabling one of those extensions- either better comments, or the inline completions extension.